# What is calling this parallax-slider.less file that is missing?

Tags: themes, server-load

I am having an issue with my WordPress load times.  Site loads very slowly, and trying to pin this to the correct issue whether it be the template/code or server related.

```
http://03e4976.netsolhost.com/site2016/
```

**First Issue -**
I am wondering why my wordpress site is looking for a parallax-slider css file that is not on the system? Site seems to work fine but is killing the load times, so how do I remove this? I am unable to see what is calling it.

> Request
>   URL:http://03e4976.netsolhost.com/site2016/wp-content/themes/theme54644/parallax-slider/less/parallax-slider.less
>   Request Method:GET Status Code:404 Not Found Remote
>   Address:206.188.192.214:80\

I believe there are other issues as well causing this load time.

Any help appreciated - Thanks
Ryan

Comment: Seems like a theme-specific issue - it would be difficult to answer without an intimate understanding of that theme's code. Your question would be best addressed in the official support channels for that theme.

Answer (score 0):

*The site is not loading at the moment and returning a `504 Gateway Time-out` error.*

Regarding the `parallax-slider.less` (or `parallax-slider.css`) file, it is most likely added by a plugin to the page.

Even though you do not have the plugin content (in this case, a slider) on the page, some files from this plugin may still be added to each page. This is often the case when plugins work with shortcodes. Parsing the complete text of each page to see if it contains a shortcode or not is a very consuming process and it is usually not recommended unless necessary. That is why, many plugins simply add their files without checking if their shortcode is used on the page or not.

Wordpress does not have a more efficient way (yet) of figuring out what pages have what shortcodes and then to load only the necessary files for them. Hopefully, in the future, this will be improved.

So, it is enough for the plugin to be activated and it may add its files to each page.

You should go look through your plugins and see which plugin may be adding this particular file. And you should also deactivate the plugins that you are not using to be sure that they do not add any unnecessary code and affect the speed of the site.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to look at MotoPress and cherry plugin as they are probably the culprit.

Comment: "Parsing the complete text of each page to see if it contains a shortcode or not is a very consuming process". That is actually not true and even if it was can be avoided by parsing the page once when saved. In other words, not loading unneeded files depends just on the skill of the author of the plugin

Comment: @MarkKaplun It seems like a consuming process to me. The Codex mentions: `Note: has_shortcode() can use a lot of resources if scanning a lot of content.` If you check on post save, it is dependent on the plugin being active and accounting for all possible ways of adding content. If not active or a way omitted, then the user will see the shortcode added but no content displaying. Also, this does not work with the shortcode generated through PHP code.

Comment: everything is relative. It is true that evaluating a complex regex is not "cheap" but relative to the cost of other things done while generating the page, namely DB access, it is nothing, and if you have page caching than you do this only once an hour while you will be serving the JS and CSS for each page request. Anyway this was just a side note that is not very relevant to the question, and what I actually meant is that the plugin authors can and should do it, and there is no need in something new in wordpress core for it

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest using a page speed tool like GTmetrix to assess your load speed - that gives you an objective measure, and rules out network peculiarities between your browser and the site server. https://gtmetrix.com/

Second, the slider is built into the theme. Check the theme options to see whether you might have accidentally left the slider on, or otherwise told the theme that it should try to get the slider.

Third, and this is a kludge that I don't really endorse, but it can solve a problem like this if you are in a hurry. Create an empty .less file and put it in that directory. And see what happens.

Fourth, it wouldn't hurt to read the theme manual, or go to the theme seller and look at their support, and if all else fails, ask them.

Fifth, use the Chrome Inspect tools or firefox firebug to look at the sites code as it's loading and building the page. If it's freezing you will have plenty of time to look at the source code that is being delivered to the browser to build the page.

Take number five here and switch that with number three.